Searching through a specific list of websites using Google Search
I'm using SerpAPI Google Search to find shopping results and I have been trying to find a way to limit my search results to come from a specific list of websites. I couldn't find any direct parameters that I could set in the API.
I tried checking for the website name in the 'link' part of the JSON response but that didn't work out either. Any recommendations?

Not sure if it works with the API, but in a normal google query you can add site:site1.com OR site:site2.com OR ..., so try to add this to the end of your query. It would be nicer with a separate parameter, of course, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As @juanpethes mentioned, the best way to do this for the Google Search API is to add site:domain.com to your q param. For example: q=Coffee site:amazon.com OR walmart.com
Sample Playground link: https://serpapi.com/playground?q=Coffee+site%3Aamazon.com+OR+site%3Awalmart.com&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&gl=us&hl=en&newPara=as_sitesearch+chips
Since you mentioned shopping results, I should note Google Shopping does not support these site:domain.com type filters. Instead, you need to refer to the filters array that SerpApi returns in a request to the Google Shopping API. There are several options within filters including Stores which provide a few a stores you can filter results too.
These are limited to what Google Shopping offers for any given search unfortunately. You cannot filter for any arbitrary store you want. This is a limitation of Google that SerpApi cannot work around.
For example:
https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_shopping&q=Coffee
"filters: [
...
 {

    "type": "Stores",
    "options":
    [
        {
            "text": "Target",
            "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google_shopping&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=target+coffee&shoprs=CAEYAioGY29mZmVlMgoIAhIGVGFyZ2V0WLfLH2AC"
        }
        ,
        {
            "text": "Walmart",
            "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google_shopping&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=walmart+coffee&shoprs=CAEYAioGY29mZmVlMgsIAhIHV2FsbWFydFi3yx9gAg"
        }
        ,
        {
            "text": "Home Depot",
            "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google_shopping&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=home+depot+coffee&shoprs=CAEYAioGY29mZmVlMg4IAhIKSG9tZSBEZXBvdFi3yx9gAg"
        }
        ,
        {
            "text": "Sears",
            "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google_shopping&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=sears+coffee&shoprs=CAEYAioGY29mZmVlMgkIAhIFU2VhcnNYt8sfYAI"
        }
    ]

  }
...
]

Use the serpapi_link for the store you want to filter by to get results only for that store. You just need to append your api_key to the request.
Disclaimer: I work for SerpApi.
